# Greyed out Wi-fi calling - LG Wing unlocked TMobile phone on Smart network

Tags: wi-fi, lg, t-mobile

My Wi-Fi calling is greyed out and I can't enable it.

[image]

I already tried hard by restarting the phone, updating the phone, and resetting the network settings, but it's still grey.

[image] [image]

Please let me know how to enable Wi-Fi calling.

Comment: Are you sure your mobile network provider supports Wifi calling?

Comment: @Robert they do according to this https://smart.com.ph/help/article/smart-help/2022/03/03/how-to-check-if-your-smartphone-has-volte-or-vowifi